# How can I enter and return a single letter properly from a sub in Perl?

Tags: perl, encryption, split

I am attempting to write a code that will encrypt letters with a basic cyclic shift cipher while leaving any character that is not a letter alone. I am trying to do this through the use of a sub that finds the new value for each of the letters. When I run the code now,it formats the result so there is a single space between every encrypted letter instead of keeping the original formatting. I also cannot get the result to be only in lowercase letters.

```
sub encrypter {
        my $letter = shift @_;
        if ($letter =~ m/^[a-zA-Z]/) {
                $letter =~ y/N-ZA-Mn-za-m/A-Za-z/;
                return $letter;
                }
        else {

                return lc($letter);
        }
}
print "Input string to be encrypted: ";
my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
print "$input   # USER INPUT\n";
my @inputArray = split (//, $input);
my $i = 0;
my @encryptedArray;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $#inputArray; $i++) {
        $encryptedArray[$i] = encrypter($inputArray[$i]);
}
print "@encryptedArray   # OUTPUT\n";
```

Comment: Some part of your code seems missed.

Comment: rot13 is simply `$input =~ y/N-ZA-Mn-za-m/A-Za-z/;`

Comment: you don't show where you call encrypter

Answer (score 2):

You might try changing this line:

```
if ($letter = m/[^a-zA-Z]/ ) {
```

To something more like this:

```
if ($letter =~ m/^[a-zA-Z]/) {
```

In the original line you are doing an assignment to the variable $letter, and the ^ will need to be before the [a-zA-Z] for the comparison.

Comment: I made the change, but I'm still getting nothing for my result

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to do a rot13 translation on your characters.  This can be done a little easier using `tr`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub rot13 {
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ tr/a-zA-Z/n-zA-Za-m/;
    return $string;
}

print "Input string to be encrypted: ";
chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);

print "$input   # USER INPUT\n";

print "Cycle of 4:\n";

for (1..4) {
    $input = rot13($input);
    print "  $input\n";
}
```

Outputs

```
Input string to be encrypted: asdf
asdf   # USER INPUT
Cycle of 4:
  nFqs
  ASDF
  NfQS
  asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a some kind of more general implementation of it, it is easier to adapt it to something like, for example, using different rotation places for different letter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(switch say);

sub rotateBy {
    my ($letter, $rotate_places) = @_;

    $rotate_places = $rotate_places ? $rotate_places : 13;
    my $width = (ord 'z') - (ord 'a') + 1;

    sub rotate {
        my ($let, $base, $places, $width) = @_;
        my $i = (ord $let) - (ord $base);
        return chr((ord $base) + ($i + $places) % $width);
    }

    given ($letter) {
        when (m/[a-z]/) {
            return rotate ($letter, 'a', $rotate_places, $width);
        }
        when (m/A-Z/) {
            return rotate ($letter, 'A', $rotate_places, $width);
        }
        default {
            return $letter;
        }
    }
}

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print "PLAINTEXT : $_\n";
    print "CIPHERTEXT: ";
    foreach my $let (split //) {
        print rotateBy($let);
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

---

By the way, the above code looks too verbose to me, maybe there is a better way to do it.